# I must be crazy.... Simple drawing issues.!

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

Hello amazing Stack Overflow members
I need some help :(

I've drawn 3 shapes to the stage using the rectangle tool. (Flash CS6).
WITHOUT making these movie clips or naming them,
How do I move them individually!?

Cheers and love your work.

Comment: You might not be able to move them individually, they might get grouped into a single graphics by Flash compiler. You have to make them movie clips to ensure that they'll be separate entities.

Comment: I figured that there was some sort of batching process going on, :(
So there is no way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them on separate layers, then use Shape Tweens.

Comment: That would probably work, however I unfortunately have to have them all on the same layer :(
(I need to break apart an imported asset and move the components)
Thanks for the answer though :)